# Rvalue ссылки и шаблоны

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

К примеру имеется следующий код:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 void foo(const std::string &t) {
  std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

 void foo(std::string &&t) {
  std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string alpha = "tmp";

  foo(alpha);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

При выполнении которого мы ожидаемо увидим, что был использован первый вариант функции с константной ссылкой `lvalue`. Однако если функции заменить шаблонами:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void foo(const T &t) {
  std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T &&t) {
  std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string alpha = "tmp";

  foo(alpha);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

То можно увидеть, что вызывается второй вариант функции с `rvalue` ссылкой. Почему? Как инстанцируются эти шаблоны?

PS конечно, можно добавить `std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value>::type`, но меня интересует почему так происходит.

Answer (score 3):

В шаблонах `&&` - это просто универсальная ссылка, которая может быть `lvalue`, может `rvalue`.

В первом случае без шаблонов нет rvalue переменной, только lvalue, потому и используется `const`-версия, принимающая lvalue.

Во втором - у нас переменная не является `const`, и используется вторая версия, которая может принять просто ссылку на строку, не константную, как более точное, не пребующее приведения типа сответствие.

Comment: Это специфческое поведение именно для шаблонов? (имею ввиду поведение `&&`)

Comment: Ну да, && в шаблонах. Для того и нужна потом идеальная передача.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, универсальная ссылька тут непричем. Точно такое же поведение будет, если вместо универсальной аргументом будет обычная ссылька. Из двух перегруженных шаблонов инстанцируется тот вариант, в котором  более точное соответствие типов.Тут действует только это правило. В данном случаи вы передаете неконстантный обьект, поэтому выбирается  тот шаблон, по которой выводится точный тип ( неконстантный)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Здесь важно то, что `&&` в шаблоне - не rvalue.

Comment: Не всякий параметр шаблона с `&&` является forwarding ссылкой